# Insert Html at clientX and ClientY position of cursor in editor having div contenteditable="true" javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

```
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>

  var html = '<div>Hi, Please insert at clientX and ClientY position of cursor in editor having div contenteditable</div>';
```

event.clientX and event.clientY can get their position as below:-

```
event.ClientX = "";
event.ClientY = "";
```

How to insert html at the ClientX and ClientY  position of cursor in `id="editor"`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to position an element at the given position of the mouse.

You said "with HTML". This is done like this (but this is static, doesn't follow the mouse):

```
<div class="myEl" style="top: 123px; left: 123px; position: fixed;">Your content</div>
```

If you meant with Javascript that outputs HTML, it's done like this inside your `mousemove` handler:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  var elStyle = document.querySelector(".myEl").style;
  elStyle.top = event.clientY + "px";
  elStyle.left = event.clientX + "px";
});
```

Note that you, in the latter example need to have `position: fixed;` defined in your CSS:

```
.myEl {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Or set it on the element:

```
<div class="myEl" style="position: fixed">
  Your content
</div>
```

Comment: updated question, its cursor and I want to insert html string